# How to efficently plan 100 jobs via cron?

Tags: cron

I am scheduling spiders deployed via scrapy with cron. Each spider one line. Now with 100 spiders this becomes quite difficult to plan and manage. What is the recommended way to manage a large amount of jobs? Looking at potential maintenance time needed to pause/resume jobs among other things like overlapping jobs etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't use cron**

If your needs are complex you might consider using a more advanced product that is designed to run complex schedules (distributed over multiple servers) and that supports triggers, job dependencies, error handling, retries and retry monitoring etc. The industry jargon would be  "enterprise" [job scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software) and/or "workload automation".

Comment: Thank you that is helpful. I found two in the list that might fit the needs, https://www.sos-berlin.com/ and https://www.schedulix.org/ . The later one seems to be apropriate for an embitious project on linux with an open source licence.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to schedule WHEN the task will be run, not HOW OFTEN, you may keep using cron. To avoid cross-executions of tasks you can let cron execute just a short script that adds the task to some sort of queue (redis, rabbitmq, sql database) and let another script consume that queue and execute the workloads sequentially or with limited concurrency. This of course brings another category of problems like how to handle stuck workloads blocking the others from being run :)